# Javax.websocket, error code = 1006, Reason = unexpected end of stream

Tags: java, websocket, bitcoin, java-websocket

I am using javax.websockets to have a webSocket connection with Blockchain.info, except that it closes down after random intervals, and I can see the close reason as:

'Unexpected end of stream', Error Code = 1006.

I am not able to figure out why this occurs. I want the connection to never close unless the application tells it to. Here is the code:

```
private void initializeWebSocketSession(Session session)
{
    WebSocketContainer container container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
    Session session = container.connectToServer(BlockchainWebSocketClient.class, URI.create("wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv"));               
}

public void onOpen(Session session) throws IOException
{
    session.setMaxIdleTimeout(0);
    session.getBasicRemote().sendText("{\"op\":\"unconfirmed_sub\"}");
}

@OnMessage
public void onMessage(String message, boolean isLastPartOfMessage)
{
    // Some logic
}
```

Comment: 1006 means "connection lost"; are you sure that you don't have any connection issues?

Comment: I started sending ping to the server after every 30 seconds and that issue is now resolved. But now I get another reason with the same close code: 'Connection reset by peer'.

Comment: You might be interested in heartbeat feature in Tyrus: https://tyrus.java.net/apidocs/1.9/org/glassfish/tyrus/core/TyrusSession.html#setHeartbeatInterval(long)

Comment: And about 'connection reset by peer' - it might be just the servers "defense" mechanism, maybe they want to prevent lots of opened connections and they have something like "hard" timeout - limiting the websocket connections based on some server criteria.

Comment: @PavelBucek: Thanks. Do you think that Tyrus would be better than the javax.webSocket implementation? Can a comparison be made?

Comment: Tyrus IS javax.websocket implementation. javax.websocket (you most likely refer to JSR 356) is just an API and there are multiple implementations. One of them is Tyrus, which is also the reference implementation (basically something which needs to be submitted when the final version of the JSR is published).